# Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.sys.geo_replication_links' is not supported in this version of SQL Server springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure

I want to execute sys.geo_replication_links to check if application is connected to primary or secondary database. however, I am not able to execute this command via spring boot.

I tried below approach but did not work.

```
 @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT partner_server FROM [master].sys.geo_replication_links")
    public String getServerName();
```

I get below error message:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.sys.geo_replication_links' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

How can I call to master from my application database ? Is there a hack. I dont want to create a new connection just for one query, Is there a smarted approach ?